# How to report the results of a glm from R in a scientific paper

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, p-value, reporting

Say I have the following results from a glm (gaussian distribution) in R:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 210.63710   60.32309   4.220 0.000124 ***
sexm         -0.47692    0.31811  -1.460 0.167893    
year         -0.19032    0.03461  -4.194 0.000356 ***
```

I am testing the difference of my dependent variable between sex and year. In this case, there is no significant difference in my dependent variable between sexes, but there is a significant difference in my dependent variable between years.

I'm wondering how to report these results in a scientific paper?

Normally, in a scientific paper, you write something along the lines of:
There was no significant difference in *dependent variable* between sex (Name of test; F = , p = ).

So for my glm, I would probably write:
(GLM (*maybe include the distribution and links here?*); **XXX**, p = )

But what would go in the place of **XXX** in this case? From this output, we don't have an F-value, so I'm unsure of how to report this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that you can call it a t-test (or whatever) and report  both the test stat and the p-value, since your paper should discuss the details of how you did your test. Ultimately, however, do it how others in that journal do it.

Comment: to add to that^, you can run general F-test's comparing a reduced model to full model. For instance, you could test the null that only sex is important in modeling the dependent variable vs. the alternative that a model with sex and year does a better job. This would give you your desired f-test, which you can compute in R using `anova("reduced", "full")`.

Comment: How you report it would depend on the journal's conventions; these vary from area to area (and sometimes, journal to journal). Some journals say very little (presumably allowing a degree of leeway), others are extremely specific.